# How to edit multiple questions at once in LimeSurvey?

Tags: limesurvey

Making trivial edits (e.g. set questions as mandatory or deleting multiple questions) can be frustratingly slow if you have to one by one. Does LimeSurvey offers a page where all questions (of a survey or question group) are listed and I can edit from there?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It's under 'Survey menu'.

[image]

ListQuestions view allows you to edit all questions in a question group. LimeSurvey display it whenever you delete a question, but doesn't offer any link/button on the admin page to go to that view.

You can, however, go to that view by browsing modified URL.

Click on the question group where you want to edit its questions. The link would looks like this,

```
example.limequery.org/admin/questiongroups/sa/view/surveyid/123456/gid/1
```

Replace `questiongroups` to `survey` and replace `view` to `listquestions`, so the URL becomes something like this,

```
example.limequery.org/admin/survey/sa/listquestions/surveyid/123456/gid/1
```

That URL is the ListQuestions view of a question group.

[image]

You can't edit the questions' code and description on that view, but you can  open the 'Edit question' of all the questions in new tabs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? 
In the current version there should be a menu entry for List questions.

Comment: yeah, I found it. But it would be easier (and more logical) to have a button to can go to that view when viewing under 'Structure'.